# Remove strings in a cell-array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

```
fullSeq='ABCDEFG'
Inputcell= {'ABC', 'BDEG','DEFG','ABCDEFG','CDEG','BCDF','ABCDEFG'}
```

I have 2 `'ABCDEFG'` strings in the above `Inputcell`. How can I remove those 2 strings? The expected output should be:

```
Outputcell= {'ABC', 'BDEG','DEFG','CDEG','BCDF'}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use logical indexing along with [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html?refresh=true):

```
OutputCell = Inputcell(~strcmp(Inputcell,fullSeq))

OutputCell = 

    'ABC'    'BDEG'    'DEFG'    'CDEG'    'BCDF'
```

yay!

Comment: Probably much simpler.  `ismember` is probably overkill for this particular application. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Simple call to [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) will do the trick combined with logical indexing:

```
fullSeq='ABCDEFG';
Inputcell= {'ABC', 'BDEG','DEFG','ABCDEFG','CDEG','BCDF','ABCDEFG'};
Outputcell = Inputcell(~ismember(Inputcell, fullSeq));
```

We get:

```
>> Outputcell
Outputcell = 
    'ABC'    'BDEG'    'DEFG'    'CDEG'    'BCDF'
```

Comment: well played! I wonder which is faster between `strcmp` and `ismember` :)

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you want to automatically delete **every** element which appears at least twice (rather than having to run the above answers with various values of `fullSeq`), you can do that too:

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{2*find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}(); %define inline 'if'
Inputcell={'ABC', 'BDEG','DEFG','ABCDEFG','CDEG','BCDF','ABCDEFG'};
Tempcell=cellfun(@(x)iif(sum(strcmp(x,Inputcell))>1,[],true,x),Inputcell,...
                 'uniformoutput',false);
Outputcell=Tempcell(~cellfun('isempty',Tempcell))
```

Result:

```
Outputcell = 

    'ABC'    'BDEG'    'DEFG'    'CDEG'    'BCDF'
```